# Bootstrap not loading on computer

Tags: spring-mvc, bootstrap.min.css

This is my very first post on stackoverflow so Hello to all!. I have a question.

I am working with some colleague son a Spring MVC project. Downloaded the bootstrap libraries (CSS / js / jQuery). Uploaded the files to GIT and we all have the same tree.

The question is. How come that the bootstrap CSS is working for them, and on my PC it isn't loading (win10/ Chrome) . The front-end works for all 3 colleagues and mine will not load.

And the peculiar thing is that it worked like 3 days ago.

I even tried making a simple index.html with the css and JS attached and it still will not load! And it doesn't work on any browser

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it.
The problem was some cached data that all my browsers share in common. I cleared Cached images, browsing data , history , etc. from the beginning .
Thread closed :).
 Good luck fellow developers